# CMake doesn't know where is Qt4 qmake

Tags: linux, qt, cmake

I am using Debian OS and I'm trying to point to cmake where is my Qt4.

I try to build qjson library and with its CMakeLists.txt:
http://pastebin.com/fKNp0Qgy

I get:

```
Qt5 not found, searching for Qt4
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1386 (message):
  Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:55 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I'm not familiar with CMake and Qt config, but I'm curious what setting force CMake FIND_PACKAGE to look into '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake' for qmake.
I have installed Qt 4.8.5 from source and I have Qt4 bin folder in completely different directory.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved my problem.

Looking for QT_SELECT with `grep` command I found that QT_SELECT is related to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf` file. From the "default" file name I assumed that it is what is seen as QT_SELECT. Other configs presented with `qtchooser -l` are in `/usr/share/qtchooser/` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser` directories.

Such a config file has two lines with paths. I just changed these lines, first pointing to my Qt bin directory and second pointing to my Qt lib directory. Then I could see that `qtchooser -print-env` shows `QTTOOLDIR` and `QTLIBDIR` to my Qt.

Then I could easily build qjson library with CMake, Qt4 was found correctly.

Comment: Awesome. This worked on Ubuntu 16.04 with Qt4. Note that those config files, while seemingly scattered between `/usr/share/...` and `/usr/lib/...`, all except one are symlinks to the actual config in `/usr/share/qtchooser/qt4-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf`. So only needs to be changed there.

Answer (score 23):

just try "sudo apt-get install qt-sdk" it works for me

Comment: Not a solution on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: 2020 tested: `apt-get install qt4-default`

Comment: The `qt-sdk` package doesn't exist anymore. we should install `libqt4-dev` instead.

Answer (score 8):

In my experience, this problem is most easily solved by putting the folder containing qmake in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: When I add this folder to PATH it still wants this  '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake', not my '/home/daniel/Programy/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/bin/qmake'

Comment: Maybe it will be useful info that directory '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin' exists in my system, but there is only 'qdbus' file.

Comment: Ok. I see there is a tool 'qtconfig'. It shows me $ qtchooser -print-env
QT_SELECT="default"
QTTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin"
QTLIBDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
I have to figure out how to point to my qt version.

Comment: My experience is actually with Qt5 - maybe CMake treats Qt4 differentlY?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the answers

https://askubuntu.com/questions/540746/ubuntu-14-04-qt5-development-libraries/540757#540757

Seems

`apt-file search Qt5CoreConfig.cmake` was what I was missing. This got me:

```
qtbase5-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake
```

Installing that seems to lead to CMake finding Qt5. `qmake` still reports the same problem when directly called though...some remnant from qt4 still installed it seems...

As for the `qmake` problem, this is fixed by:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was just that qtchooser was missing the "default" configuration.
I figured cmake is just executing qtchooser and looking for a "default" configuration file name.
You can install any configuration file by doing the following:

```
qtchooser -install <arbitrary_name> <path_to_qmake>
```

In my case I simply provided "default" as the arbitrary name... this created the default.conf file in the appropriate locations and all is well.  I don't think there is a limit to how many named versions of qt you have.
If you do this as root it should work for all users.

Answer (score 1):

On my old RHEL distro, this did it for me:

```
sudo yum install qt-devel.x86_64
```

Just the qt-base one wouldn't work with cmake.

Answer (score 1):

1) Where is your qtchooser configuration file?

```
  $: locate qtchooser | grep conf
```

2) From the list of conf files, probably there is one call "default.conf"
  This one is a link to one of the others (4.conf or qt4.conf or 5.conf or qt5.conf).
  Choose the one that makes sense too you, and create a link to it.

Suppose your default file path is

/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf

Create backup:

```
  $: cd $(dirname /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt-default/qtchooser/default.conf)
  $: cp -av default.conf default.conf_backup
```

Let's say you target is 
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/qt5.conf

Then:

```
  $: sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/qt5.conf default.conf
```

3) Is the path to your qmake right?

Check qmake location

```
  $: locate qmake | grep bin
```

Is the same one as indicated in your modified qtchooser/default.conf?

```
  $: cat /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/qt5.conf
```

If the answer is YES, then you are done.
  If the anser is no, then you need to modify the file:

Create backup:

```
  $: cd $(dirname /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qtchooser/qt5.conf)
  $: cp -av qt5.conf qt5.conf_backup
```

Edit file and change path to your qmake location

```
  $ sudo vi qt5.conf
```

Now it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution was add a link in the directory that the gem expected to find it. On Ubuntu 14.04 it qmake lives in /usr/bin.  Simple solution.