# cmake not working, could not exec qmake

Tags: cmake, qmake

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I'm trying to install a program which requires cmake. When I run `cmake src/` I get:

```
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I read on [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113575/cmake-doesnt-know-where-is-qt4-qmake) that the problem has something to do with CMake not being able to find Qt4 qmake.

However in my case, it was simply a matter of not having qt4-qmake. This solved it (but weighs a heavy 440MB):

```
sudo apt-get install qt-sdk
```

Comment: In my case, after installing this I also had to install libqt5webkit: 
sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev

Comment: If you're counting calories, you may be able to get away with just `sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake`.

Comment: @bonh Or, as in my similar case, `sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev`.

Answer (score 90):

Does the trick:

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake
```

You do **not** need to install half a gigabyte of qt sdk!

Comment: libqt4-dev add extra stuff required to compile some dependencies

Comment: worked with qt5-make for me

Answer (score 36):

For newer versions of Ubuntu, if you have only installed version 5 of the Qt Framework, you may get this error. If you want to use Qt version 5 by default, then you should run the following command to fix the error:

```
sudo apt install qt5-default
```

Answer (score 24):

You need the `qt` dependences:

`sudo apt-get install qt4-qmake libqt4-dev`

Answer (score 4):

as it says in docs: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#debian--ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qt5-default libqt5webkit5-dev gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x
```

works for me in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

You can use QtCreator to compile the cmake project too. This is only advantageous over the accepted answer if you already have QtCreator installed, I notice you are using a qmake project so this might be likely.

The main advantage of this is that qt creator will be configured to use the qmake tool without the need to install the command line configured version of qmake.

Incidentally, I get this error if I try to run the qmake executable bundled with QtCreator on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also suffering from this issue and solved it using this approach after using many solutions.

1. Use the 'find' command to locate 'qmake':

```
sudo find / -name qmake 2>/dev/null
```

This command will show possible locations of 'qmake' on your system.

2. Check the content of the Qt bin directory:

```
ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/
```

Ensure that 'qmake' is present in this directory.

3. Create a symbolic link to the correct location:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /usr/lib/qt5/bin/qmake
```

This ensures the correct path is used.

4. Update the PATH in the '.bashrc' file:

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

This ensures the correct Qt bin directory is included.

5. Retry the 'qmake --version' command:

```
qmake --version
```

Confirm that 'qmake' is now recognized. if the terminal is stuck then don't worry restart the system or you can create a new project using qt-creator and choose desktop kit it will work perfectly.