# qt5: cannot find -lGL

Tags: qt, installation, apt-get

I am using Qt5 in my project, but after I reinstall my Ubuntu 15.04 today, I cannot compile my code in Qt Creator. I got two error messages as

```
cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anyone has any idea? I used to solve it by install a library:

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
```

But it doesn't work for me now. This is what I got from the terminal:
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglu1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                             libgl-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: It does not seem a Qt issue, but rather an Ubuntu issue... So maybe this is not the right place to ask that... Anyway have your tried googling? You can find a lot of resources about your problem... For example [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) is the first result I've found... it could be a good starting point for working out your problem

Comment: Have you tried to `apt-get install libgl-dev` and `apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev`? They are required by this package but not automatically installed. (Maybe different default settings in Ubuntu 15?)

Comment: @Felix, I have, then it says some other dependencies need to be installed.

Comment: "sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev" only works in Ubuntu 15.04. It doesn't work in 15.10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cmake not working, could not exec qmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703864/cmake-not-working-could-not-exec-qmake)